# git is not updating the master branch - any clue why or how to solve it?

Tags: git

If I do

```
git checkout master
```

`git push`

I get

> Everything up-to-date

If I go

```
git pull
```

I get

> Already up-to-date.

If I ssh to my server remotely and I do:

```
 git status
```

I get:

> On branch master 
>   nothing to commit (working directory clean)

However, the truth is, I DO have a different version of a file locally when compared with the remote one.

How can I solve this, in order to place my local file into the master remote branch ?

Comment: Did you make a change to the file while you were on the master branch?
What does `git status` give you locally?
Are you sure that the file is tracked?

Comment: "However, the truth is, I DO have a different version of a file locally when compared with the remote one." How do you know this? All the evidence that you've shown suggests otherwise.

Comment: the file IS tracked. A fellow dev as pulled from master and he does have the right new updated file. However, if I directly check that file (is a PDF) on the remote address I can see it's NOT the same!!

Comment: What is the remote address that you are checking? Most "central" git repositories are bare and don't have working trees. Is there some deployment process from your "central" repository that needs to be performed? If another developer has successfully pulled from master it suggests that you *have* successfully checked in and pushed your changes.

Comment: You cannot push to a checked-out branch of a remote repository. So whatever is on your server, it is not the branch or remote repository you are pushing to. Is it possible that you cloned it locally on your server from a different place? (In that case: pull there)

Comment: the remote address is a remote url.  We do have a bare repo. We normally work on dev, we checkout master, we merge dev into master, we push master... this is the workflow...

Comment: When you say "we push master", where do you push master? Who updates the working tree / checked out branch of whatever non-bare repository that you push to?

Comment: From my local machine, from my local master branch, I do "git push" and it pushed to master branch. How ? Using a hook. What does the hook ? Navigates to the master working tree `/home/www/myworkingdirectoryonmaster` do unset `GIT_DIR` then `git pull hub master`

Comment: Should I connect remotely and do `git pull hub master` or better not ?

Comment: You can at least do a `git fetch` and see if you get anything new that wasn’t there before. That should give you a hint if your hook is actually working correctly. It might be a good idea to check the log too.

Comment: I have done `git pull hub master` and it `got the file that was not updated´ what does this mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have done `git pull hub master` and it `catched the file that was not updated´ what does this mean ?

That means that you did everything correctly on your local machine. You commited the changes correctly, and you pushed it correctly. The not working thing is where changes go from the central (bare) repository, to the other (non-bare) repository with the working directory. You said that a hook is resposible for that, so that does not seem to work.

Comment: for some weird reason that I don't get, after that, we have change another file, I have done the same thing, and we got everything updated. I recall do have done a git reset HARD and a git clean before doing all this, and that file was there, SO, perhaps it was related somehow. Anyhow... deploying with git is really a thin line to cross when you not master it...

Comment: Btw. it might be a good idea to do `git fetch hub && git reset --hard hub/master` instead of the pull, so it will actually always use whatever is on hub’s master branch, to prevent any merge conflicts.

Comment: are you suggesting that we should, on our hook configuration, instead of having `git pull hub master` we change it to `git fecht hub && git reset --hard hub/master` ?

Comment: Yeah, I think that’s more safe against conflicts that could happen due to local changes in that repository (and it will also work in case you ever force-push something).

Comment: should I write the command exactly as you suggested with hub/master OR should I have hub OR master there ?

Comment: With exactly `hub/master` as that specifies the exact branch (it will refer to the `master` of the remote repository `hub`).

Comment: if it's not requesting to much, can you please briefly describe on your answer, what will that command do, precisely ? I'm really interested on learning more then just copy / paste the above. If you, however, believe that this should belong to another specific question, I can create one as well. Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

You may have an uncommitted file locally. In your local work dir, try:

```
git add -A
git commit -m "commit message"
git push
```

Comment: please check my last question comment.